# Rsyslog - Change Default Log Directory(/var/log) for multiple clients

Tags: logs, remote, rsyslog

I have 2 Clients connected to my rsyslog server.
I want to change the default log directory for each client.
So client A writes to /var/log/ClientA and client B writes to /var/log/clientB.

I am looking forward to your help, as i can't implement it that way.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem with `rsyslog` templates. For example, just put in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` the following lines:

```
$template DynamicFile,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/forwarded-logs.log" 
*.* -?DynamicFile
```

Source/Further reading: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/log-aggregation-rsyslog